# How do I create a UISearchController programmatically and connect to it?

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, xcode7, uisearchcontroller

I added a `UISearchBar` and a `UISearchDisplayController` to my application. Unfortunately, `UISearchDisplayController` is deprecated in iOS 8, and Xcode 7.1 doesn't have the *combination* of `UISearchBar` and `UISearchController` in Interface Builder yet.

So, my question is: How do I create a `UISearchController` programmatically and connect the `UISearchBar` to it outside of Interface Builder, both of which I have never done in the 5 years of Objective-C programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **UISearchController** instead of **UISearchBar** or UISearchDisplayController visit to see full documentation and [code sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: The sample code was exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you so much... I really appreciate it.